# Project builds but Omnisharp doesn't see a nuget package and shows error

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, .net-core, mono, omnisharp

I'm on linux ([elementaryOS](https://elementary.io/), Ubuntu-based) and have both .NET Core (3.0.100) and Mono (6.4.0.198) installed. For C# development I use VS Code with the [Omnisharp](https://www.omnisharp.net/) extension. I'm trying to build a [sample project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/f56943da83b56f21086f8bd4124436dfc4434f34/BoxView/GameOfLife) using Xamarin.Forms.

My problem is that even though **I can successfully build the project** with Mono, Omnisharp is complaining about a missing Xamarin.Forms reference:

```
The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234)
```

I checked it, and it is included in the `.csproj`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.2.0.709249" />
</ItemGroup>
```

My suspition is that maybe Omnisharp tries to communicate with .NET Core instead of Mono. (Since I need to target a version of .NET Framework, I have to build it with Mono.) This is how I build the project with Mono:

```
$ nuget restore
$ cd GameOfLife/GameOfLife
$ msbuild
$ cd ../GameOfLife.Android
$ msbuild /t:Build,Install
```

I know I can't possibly build the project with .NET Core, but I tried at least fetching nuget packages:

```
$ dotnet restore
→ ./GameOfLife/GameOfLife/GameOfLife.Android/GameOfLife.Android.csproj :
  warning NU1503: Skipping restore for project './GameOfLife/GameOfLife
  /GameOfLife.Android/GameOfLife.Android.csproj'. The project file may be
  invalid or missing targets required for restore. [./GameOfLife/GameOfLife.sln]

$ cd GameOfLife/GameOfLife.Android
$ dotnet restore
→ (nothing happened)

$ dotnet add GameOfLife.Android.csproj package Xamarin.Forms
→ ./GameOfLife/GameOfLife/GameOfLife.Android/GameOfLife.Android.csproj(85,3):
  error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Xamarin
  /Android/Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path
  in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
→ Unable to create dependency graph file for project 'GameOfLife.Android.csproj'.
  Cannot add package reference.
```

The last error means that Xamarin.Android is only installed for Mono (it's *not possible* to install it for .NET Core), but I don't know whether this is blocking the installation of Xamarin.Forms, or whether it's just an urelated error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is gone after closing and reopening VS Code